# Chrome extension and XHR with permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a Chrome extension and I've some issue with a XHR cross-domain. Let me explain: I set right permission in `manifest.json` for a domain and I make (in my js file) a simple XMLHttpRequest. Request works fine but `responseXML` field is `null`. Why? It is not an issue with SOP and `responseText` correctly contains HTML text of the page requested. How I can parse it? I can't do it with `DOMParser().parseFromString`even with using https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser implementation, I receive everytime a single.

Some suggestions? My (simple) code is following:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "http://somedomain.com", true);

req.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
req.onload = anonymousFunction;

req.send(null);
```

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: Naturally, I could use a iframe on my internal html but I was looking for a less "rude" way :P

Comment: "It is not an issue with SOP", you sure?

Comment: I'm sure, cause I tried without permissions and yes, in that case I receive an error about SOP. Anyway, if it would be a SOP issue I don't receive responseText correct, too.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same, I'm coming around several users with low points and abandoned questions